# 'Oject required' error using Cell.Find with If Statement

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on some VBA that will search the worksheet for a particular word or phrase, if it comes across that word or phrase, I would like for it to grab the whole column and copy it. Unfortunately, I keep running into an issue when I try and set the search result equal to my variable.

```
Dim Srch As Range

 Set Srch = Cell.Find(What:="Foundation Account", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
   If Not Srch Is Nothing Then
         'Do something
```

Each time I run this I get a run-time error 424 'Object required'. Is there a reason why I am unable to Set `Srch` = `Cell.Find`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cell.find` expression has the wrong syntax - you have to define the range where it is looking. Try changing it to `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(.......)` or

```
  Dim ws as worksheet
  'delcaring the rest of the variables
  ws.Cells.find(......)
```

In the future - try reading [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) on the methods and functions you are trying to use - that is how I learned almost everything I know today. And SO, of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
Public function findWord(sheetName as string, whatimlookingfor as string)

    Dim Srch As Range
    Dim oWs as Worksheet
    Dim oWb as Workbook

    Set oWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set oWs = oWb.Sheets(sheetName)


     Set Srch = oWs.Cell.Find(What:=whatimlookingfor, After:=oWs.Range("A1"), LookIn:= _
            xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

       If Not Srch Is Nothing Then
          oWs.Columns(Srch.column).Select
          Selection.Copy
       End if

End function
```

Comment: You should really explain what exactly you are doing, and why. Otherwise this isn't very helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this wont be the same sheet every time. Setting the sheets to a specific value wouldn't help me much.

Comment: i edit my previous answer. Now you can do whatever you need to do once you've find your cell.